# Angular: Refresh on browser is not passing data to child component

Tags: angular

I have two components - a parent and child who are responsible for displaying some data from an external api call as a list in the child component. Let's call these - ParentComponent and ChildComponent.

ParentComponent.component.ts

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any[] = new Array();
  loading: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItems();
  }
  
    private getItems() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.apiService.get<any>('/some-external-api')
        .subscribe(r => {
            r.prop.forEach(p => {
                this.items.push(p);
            });
            this.loading = false;
        }, 
        e => {
          this.loading = false;
          alert(e);
        })   
  }

}
```

ParentComponent.html

```
<div class="table-container">
    <app-child-component *ngIf="!loading" [items]="items"></app-child-component>
    <app-spinner *ngIf="loading && items.length === 0" [class.loading]="items.length == 0"></app-spinner>
</div>
```

ChildComponent.component.ts

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() items: any;
 //skipping rest code
}
```

ChildComponent.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" class="curve-row">
<!-- skipping details (generating a table)-->
</div>
```

Now the problem is that as long as I am navigating within the app, all of this is working just fine. The parent component is correctly passing the data to child component.

The problem arises when I refresh the page manually. Let's say the route for the above parent component is `/parent`. If I am on `/parent` route already and I manually refresh the page, I no longer see data being shown correctly by the child (a html table basically..in this case it comes as empty). In the network console I can see that a call is made to the external api by the parent and the data also comes back just fine. But looks like the child is rendered before the data is received from the external api. If I then navigate to another tab and then come back to parent, I can see the data once again.

How do I make sure that this still works on page refreshes ?

I am sure this is a rookie mistake as I am new to Angular. Appreciate any help here !

### Update

Making below changes fixed it.

ParentComponent.component.ts

```
    export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
      items: any[] = new Array();
      loading: boolean = false;
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getItems();
      }
      
        private getItems() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.apiService.get<any>('/some-external-api')
            .subscribe(r => {
                this.items = r.props;
                this.loading = false;
    if (someCondition){
    this.items = this.items.filter(i=>i.somekey==='some-val') // how about this ? This stops working again once I put this line.    
}
            }, 
            e => {
              this.loading = false;
              alert(e);
            })   
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: You should not mutate objects that you intend to show in the template or asynchronously pass to children (ignoring objects meant for this, like `Subject`s). When you mutate an object (`this.items.push`), Angular can't detect the change, so it doesn't update the template. Change `r.prop.forEach(p => { this.items.push(p); });` to `this.items = r.prop` and try it again. Angular can detect reassignments, so this should work.

Comment: I'd even say `this.items = [...r.prop]` to avoid sharing references.

Comment: I figured sharing would be fine since the source of `r` likely isn't using the reference after returning it, but ya, that's a typical, safe way to avoid sharing references.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks. That fixed the problem. But what If I do need to mutate the object...for example, filter few objects out before passing them to child component. Where should that code go...should it remain in parent or go to child component ? Please see the updates on the question above

Comment: I'm not sure why that doesn't work. Are you sure you aren't just accidentally filtering out all the items?